# How to make ⌘N open a new window in Safari?

Tags: safari, shortcut

⌘N currently opens a new tab in Safari, but I would like for that key command to open a new window (like in Chrome). Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Does System Preferences ==> Keyboard ==> Shortcuts not work?

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you using? I'm asking because the default on **macOS Catalina** in **Safari** is that **⌘N** opens a new _window_. That said, In **System Preferences** > **Dock**  if **Prefer tabs when opening documents:** is set to **Always** that will cause a _tab_ to open instead of a new _window_.

Comment: @user3439894 answered it! thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **System Preferences** > **Dock** if **Prefer tabs when opening documents:** is set to **Always** that will cause a *tab* to open instead of a new *window*.

Changing it to **Manually** will allow **⌘N** to open in a new *window*.

<sup>There is also an **In Full Screen Only** *option*.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Basically user3439894s answer but on macOS BigSur, the option is located in **System Preferences -> General** menu.

[image]

Comment: thx! (however I find the way this works kind of unpleasant and counter-intuitive)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the setting for one particular app, then you can use a `defaults write` command to do that:

```
defaults write -app <name> AppleWindowTabbingMode -string never
```

Other options to try include `manual`, `always`, and `fullscreen`.

The app should not be running when you edit the plist.

[Shell command to change "Prefer tabs when opening documents"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/424148/shell-command-to-change-prefer-tabs-when-opening-documents)