# Shell command to change "Prefer tabs when opening documents"

Tags: command-line, big-sur, preferences

In macOS System Preferences->General you can change "Prefer tabs when opening documents" option to "never" or "always" etc.

I would like to enable this feature for all apps but LiveCode, so I need to know the shell command to change this option to "never" or to "always", so I can use it on activating/deactivating the app.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to keep changing the Global Preferences: you can set the preferences per app with:

```
defaults write -app LiveCode AppleWindowTabbingMode -string manual
```

Other options to try include `never`, `always`, and `fullscreen`.

The app should not be running when you edit the plist.

Comment: Thank you very much, benwiggy, exactly what I need!